# Visual Studio Code cripples my computer running dozens of instances of pylint, etc

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pylint

I have a project that contains about 60 Python files, and I have VSCode set up to run a couple different pylinters.  This has proved to be very useful, but when I start editing my project, my computer gets totally pummeled from VSCode running dozens of instances of the pylinters at the same time.

I find it pretty silly that VSCode does not automatically throttle itself, since it's not hard to determine the computer load and number of cores available.  If it matters, I'm running on Windows.  I use VSCode regularly on Linux, but have never used it with a large Python project.

I've tried searching for this information using many different queries, but have never been able to find any help for my question:

Can I specify a limit the number of processes that VSCode can spawn at once, or somehow regulate it to keep it from rendering my computer almost useless for minutes at a time?

Comment: Could you elaborate on how you have "VSCode set up to run a couple different pylinters"? The exact plugins/tools/configurations seem relevant

Comment: I have "Lint On Save" turned on, but it's also very obvious it checks everything as I change something.  I have it configured to run MyPy and Prospector.  I used to use more linters, but I got too many duplicates. 

I have "Analysis Mode" set to "openFilesOnly", but it's not hard to get a lot of files open when working for a little while.   It does seem like it wants to lint everything in the project when it starts, based on the number of Python processes it spawns.

Comment: @ConceptJunkie `prospector` looks slowly, have you tried to disable it?

Comment: Sure, I can try that, but it seems like a case of, "Doctor, it hurts when I do that."  "Well don't do that."

It seems to me that it should be incumbent on VSCode to not spawn so many processes that it hammers your computer.

Comment: @ConceptJunkie I agree with that.